# Proving functor laws for IO instance

Tags: haskell, functor

How can I prove the functor laws for the `IO` instance, which is:

```
instance Functor IO where
    fmap f action = do
        result <- action
        return (f result)
```

These are the steps that I have used:

```
fmap id m == fmap id action
          == id action

fmap (f.g) action = ?
(fmap f . fmap g) action = ?
```

Comment: That's a bit like using exp (_a_ + _b_) = exp _a_ ⋅ exp _b_ = exp _b_ ⋅ exp _a_ = exp (_b_ + _a_) to prove commutativity of addition... namely: with `do` syntax, you exploit the `Monad` instance, and every monad is first and foremostly a functor. — I don't think it's really possible to prove that `IO` obeys all the laws, since its semantics are fundamentally intertwined with runtime evaluation. In fact it's somewhat contested if `IO` _is_ properly law-abiding. But normally, we can quite well take it as something of an _axiom_ that `IO` obeys the laws.

Comment: Since you are already using the monadic definition of the `IO` monad, (even with `ApplicativeDo`, applicative is strong enough too), you can simply use the fact that `fmap f = (>>= return . f)` for monads.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If I understand correctly, the `IO` newtype is a special state monad. Can you not just prove the laws for `State` in that case?

Comment: @ThreeFx: kinda, I suppose; but `RealWorld` is “deeply magical”. That's not too helpful when you're trying to prove something.

Comment: The magical nature of `RealWorld` shouldn't affect the `Functor` instance of `State a` (okay, `State# a` really), though, should it, since `fmap` doesn't (and cannot) make any assumptions about `a`?

Comment: Please don't think of `IO` as a "special state monad".  That's an admitted hack in the GHC implementation. As a conceptual model it becomes utterly ridiculous when you incorporate concurrency (`forkIO`, `MVar`).